Does it make sense to activate retain_graph after .zero_grad() and forward_pass? retain_graph = True in loss.backward() call, Pytorch
My question is,
What implies to retain the graph computed at the iteration even if we then call a forward pass on the network with other inputs?
I suppose optimizer.step() is called after every loss.backward() and than retain_graph=False is set after n iteration during which the inputs, in each iteration, are picked from different distribution per iteration. Model.zero_grad() is always called after oprimizer.step().
I am asking this to see if there is any benefit from retaining the graph where training the model in the iteration with a step that is sensibly different from the previous or the next one, like we ideally want to converge to an optimal solution for an ensemble of minimization problems.
I tried to implement retain_graph=True calling optimizer.step() after the n iteration, but this apparently didn`t improve the model performance.
